# Cost comparison of running computationally intensive function on Azure Function vs Azure Virtual Machines?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

If I look at the pricing examples of running an Azure functions, versus running a virtual machine running those same functions, here is what I see on the Azure pricing site:

Running 3M functions each which takes one second and required 500MB of memory: $18.00 (invocations cost + computer cost)

Running 3M seconds on Azures cheapest virtual machine with at least 500MB of memory:
(B1S instance, $0.008/hour):  $6.67

I'm wondering if that comparison is fair in the simplest cases (where the functions are don't perform a lot of i/o, or use other Azure services) -- particularly whether whatever machine Azure uses to run Azure functions will run those same 3M functions at the same speed per function as the B1S Virutual machine instance?  In other words, is the B1S instance as efficient per unit time as the Azure function running machines given the same memory requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must look at your usage profile. Do the request come constantly at a steady rate? Or are they spread out?

With a virtual machine you pay for the time it is running, it is not dependent on what it is doing.

With an Azure function consumption plan you pay per request. So when there are no requests there is no charge.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/ (Your 18 USD comes from this page?)

When a function has 500 MB to use, your code can use all the memory. When a VM has 500 MB of RAM a significant portion is used by the operating system.

Edit:
As Ken mentioned in the comment with a VM you need to look after the server, so you also need to take that cost into consideration.

The compute capacity is the same given a steady constant continuous use where you turn off the VM when the 3M calls are finished. But the VM has additional costs that also need to be taken into consideration.

Note when you turn the VM off you still pay for the storage of the disks.

Comment: I understand the issue around usage profile.  The use case presume a fairly constant load over time. As to memory consumption the cheapest  virtual machine comes with 1Gig of memory.  I presume at least half of that is available for running programs.  What I want to know is if the speed of machines running Azure functions is approximatly equal to the cheapest virtual instances running similar functions.

Comment: (And also bear in mind that virtual machines can be added or removed from the work pool.  Not as fast maybe as the capacity of Azure functions itself to handle lumpy loads, but maybe fast enough (depending on the use case) to be economically viable given the 300% price differential.

Comment: There is no way to make this an Apples-to-Apples comparison, this is PaaS vs IaaS.  With a VM you need to "pay" for someone to care and feed (patch, update, secure).  With a Functions you just need to worry about your code, which will also need to be patched, updated and secured but that's true for the code running on the VM.

Comment: My question is simply whether the comparison of compute capacity, (instructions per second) of an Azuare function (priced in seconds of compute) is greater less than or equal to the comput capacity of B1S virtual machine (also priced in seconds)  for a given amount of memory required. All these other issues, regarding the usage profile, maintenance cost etc. are interesting considerations, depending on the use case, but are not the question I'm asking.  If you are all avoiding answering it because you dont know the answer, that's fine, but it doesn't make the question impossible to answer.

Comment: The compute capacity is the same given a steady constant continuous use where you turn off the VM when the 3M calls are finished. But the VM has additional costs that also need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz.  That's what I needed to understand.